# How do I Connect RStudio with MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: rstudio, shiny, mongodb-atlas

I singed up freely at mongodb Atlas and created cluster, i cant find any documentation to connect to mongodb atlas from R . can any one help me out connecting R so that i can fetch data from mongo into R